# How can we share channel consumer as api?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-celery, django-channels

I have created a channel that implements some text operations using a shared task which returns the response back to the channel layer.

```
#consumers.py

import json
import pdb
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

from . import tasks

COMMANDS = {
    'help': {
        'help': 'Display help message.',
    },
    'sum': {
        'args': 2,
        'help': 'Calculate sum of two integer arguments. Example: `sum 12 32`.',
        'task': 'add'
    },
    'status': {
        'args': 1,
        'help': 'Check website status. Example: `status twitter.com`.',
        'task': 'url_status'
    },
}

class Consumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # response_message = 'Please type `help` for the list of the commands.'
        message_parts = message.split()
        if message_parts:
            command = message_parts[0].lower()
            if command == 'help':
                response_message = 'List of the available commands:\n' + '\n'.join([f'{command} - {params["help"]} ' for command, params in COMMANDS.items()])
            elif command in COMMANDS:
                if len(message_parts[1:]) != COMMANDS[command]['args']:
                    response_message = f'Wrong arguments for the command `{command}`.'
                else:
                    getattr(tasks, COMMANDS[command]['task']).delay(self.channel_name, *message_parts[1:])
                    # response_message = f'Command `{command}` received.'
        response_message = message
        await self.channel_layer.send(
                self.channel_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': response_message
                }
            )

#tasks.py
@shared_task
def add(channel_layer, x, y):
    message = '{}+{}={}'.format(x, y, int(x) + int(y))
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)({"type": "chat.message", "message": message})
```

I want to share this channel as an api which could be accessed using http request. for which i have written following views.

```
views.py
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def api(request):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
    ret = async_to_sync(channel_layer.receive)(channel_name)
    return JsonResponse({"msg":ret})
```

While receiving from the views I get the same message that I have sent. How can I share the channel or handle incoming messages without connecting using WebSockets from the template?

Answer (score 1):

### If you just want the `POST` request to send a message

```py
views.py
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def api(request):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'chat.message'})
    return JsonResponse({"msg":"sent"})
```

You will need to ensure you have subscribed to `test_channel` in your consumer. And you will need a method on that consumer `chat_message`.

### If you want to wiat for the response in your post

your not going to be able to do this using `channel_layer.send` since that is async to the extend that you dont have any concept fo response. In addition there might not even be an instance of your consumer running since Channels only creates instances when it has open websocket connections that rout to them.

so I think you can do either:

To create an instance of your consumer and send message to it from synchronise python code is going to be very complex. I suggest you do not do this approach It is complex, dirty and likely to break in all sorts of un-expected

instead I suggest to **move the code** you want to share between your HTTP view and your websocket view into a single place (not part of the consumer) were they both can call these functions.

Comment: But I want it to be asynchronous as I am making a third party chatbot. So won't it affect the response time?

Comment: do you want the POST to just to send a message?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Comment: So what will be the role of WebSocket in that case

Comment: for the user to be informed of a sent message